# How Do You Sort A Series of Lists Within A Single List

Tags: python, sorting

I have a single list which is composed of 12798 other lists, all of these lists having a huge number and a timestamp, e.g.

```
[277183164715153, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z']
```

I want to sort all these entries and I've used two method in an attempt to do this. I first tried:

```
sorted(list[i], key=itemgetter(0))
```

Then when that didn't work, I tried this:

```
sorted(list[i], key = lambda x:x[0])
```

and the results I receive from doing this have parts of the list which are sorted just fine, but then gaps where the sorting falters, e.g.

```
[275208712169482, '2022-01-05T05:13:10Z']
[281147911687289, '2022-01-05T05:12:57Z']
[602180135186, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z']
[5643554219593, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z']
[6008092591608, '2022-01-05T05:14:42Z']
[14355814742038, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z']
[19342767454394, '2022-01-05T05:16:18Z']
```

Am I using the sorting techniques incorrectly or is there something else I can try.

Comment: What is `i` in `list[i]`?

Comment: So you want to sort a list of lists where order is determined by the first element of the inner list?

Comment: NB: `sorted` does not change its argument but create sorted copy.

Comment: Sorry, its actually a list of list of lists, so list[i] is the list I want to sort which has all the many lists within. And yes, I want to sort the list of lists by the first element of the inner most nested list.

Comment: `list[i] = sorted(list[i], key=itemgetter(0))` or `list[i].sort(key=itemgetter(0))`.

Answer (score 0):

It just works out of the box:

```
list_to_order = [[3, '2022-01-05T05:13:10Z'],
[10, '2022-01-05T05:12:57Z'],
[15, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'],
[2, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z'],
[1, '2022-01-05T05:14:42Z'],
[0, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'],
[999, '2022-01-05T05:16:18Z']]

list_ordered = sorted(list_to_order)
```

Returns:

```
[[0, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [1, '2022-01-05T05:14:42Z'], [2, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z'], [3, '2022-01-05T05:13:10Z'], [10, '2022-01-05T05:12:57Z'], [15, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [999, '2022-01-05T05:16:18Z']]
```

With your set of numbers:

```
list_to_order
[[275208712169482, '2022-01-05T05:13:10Z'], [281147911687289, '2022-01-05T05:12:57Z'], [602180135186, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [5643554219593, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z'], [6008092591608, '2022-01-05T05:14:42Z'], [14355814742038, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [19342767454394, '2022-01-05T05:16:18Z']]
list_ordered
[[602180135186, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [5643554219593, '2022-01-05T05:17:39Z'], [6008092591608, '2022-01-05T05:14:42Z'], [14355814742038, '2022-01-05T05:17:41Z'], [19342767454394, '2022-01-05T05:16:18Z'], [275208712169482, '2022-01-05T05:13:10Z'], [281147911687289, '2022-01-05T05:12:57Z']]
```

Just to be sure:

```
602180135186 < 5643554219593 < 6008092591608 < 14355814742038 < 19342767454394 < 275208712169482 < 281147911687289
True
```

Comment: I gave that a go, however I still get the same issue with the same numbers. It basically produces the same order as if I used the other methods I tried.

Comment: It ordered them fine with your numbers as well.